# VBA Loop to fill numbers in a combobox

Tags: vba, for-loop

Not sure why this seemingly simple piece of code keeps crashing excel for me:

```
Dim i as Long

For i = 0.25 to 10 step 0.25
    me.combobox1.addItem (i)
Next i
```

Seems pretty straight forward, I want my combobox to have a list that looks as such:

0.25
0.50
0.75
1.00
.
.
.
10.00

Comment: `Dim i as Double` and `me.combobox1.addItem Format(i, "0.00")`

Comment: You cannot have decimals for a Long. Use Single or Double. Note stepping with decimals may not be accurate!

Comment: Oh that makes sense, duh. Thanks. Would you recommend I just looked through an array?

Comment: Oh thanks Slai, I missed your response. That worked for me

Comment: Most languages require that loop counters in a `for` be of an ordinal (integer) type. Not sure why you would think you could declare i as Long and then assign a floating point number to it.

Comment: hi @PatricK just a side note, `step 0.25` though a bit odd, is accepted by VBA.

Comment: @curious I think PatricK was suggesting that floating point errors might occur when stepping with decimals.

Comment: ya that pt is well taken n credit goes to PatricK being among the 1st to notify that. i was rather referring to "Note stepping with decimals may not be accurate". as we know that formatting aside, the only correction needs for the code to work is `Dim i As Double`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shorter version without loop:

```
ComboBox1.List = [text(row(1:40)/4,"0.00")]
```

Comment: Or `[transpose(text(row(1:40)/4,"0.00"))]` to get the trailing zeroes

Comment: thanks @YowE3K wasn't sure if text would cause an issue

Comment: LOL - Either was I, but I decided to try it and surprised myself when it worked!

Answer (score -1):

maybe try getting rid of i from "Next i" i.e use only Next instead of Next 1